# python and phoenixdb on Ubuntu (or Windows). How to?

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, apache-phoenix

I have created a python script connecting to a Phoenix HBase to analyze some data. I want to set this script up on crontab on a ubuntu server that I have running.

The script is perfectly able to run on my Windows 10 machine. But when I try to use the phoenixdb connector on Ubuntu I get an error on RunTime.

```
>>> import phoenixdb
>>> url = '<some-url>'
>>> conn = phoenixdb.connect(url, autocommit=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/phoenixdb/avatica.py", line 156, in connect
self.connection.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
(self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/phoenixdb/__init__.py", line 63, in connect
client.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/phoenixdb/avatica.py", line 158, in connect
    raise errors.InterfaceError('Unable to connect to the specified service', e)
phoenixdb.errors.InterfaceError: ('Unable to connect to the specified service', TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out'), None, None)
```

I was hoping someone here knows a way to fix this problem?

I am running Python 3.6 on Windows and Python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu, but I doubt that that is the problem.

EDIT:
I have now started a Windows 2012 Server and have tried setting my script up here as well, and it seems not to be a problem solely for Ubuntu. I am getting the exact same error on Windows.

```
>>> import phoenixdb
>>> url = '<some-url>'
>>> conn = phoenixdb.connect(url, autocommit=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\phoenixdb\avatica.py", line 156, in connect
self.connection.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
(self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 722, in create_connection raise err
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\phoenixdb\__init__.py", line 63, in connect
client.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\phoenixdb\avatica.py", line 158, in connect
raise errors.InterfaceError('Unable to connect to the specified service', e)

phoenixdb.errors.InterfaceError: ('Unable to connect to the specified service',
TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None), None, None)
```

I recently did format the PC that I developed the script on. The was using this phoenixdb connector, and I did not experience a similar problem on that.

I did also try to install Python 3.6 on the Windows machine (similar to the same python version that I installed on my normal PC - the one I developed the script on).

I'm really lost for finding a solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. It had nothing to do with the machines I set up my script on. It had to do with security settings on the AWS Machines that both the Ubuntu and Windows Servers were.